Type autocompletion for populated mongoose document
I am using mongoose with Nextjs. If you look at the Review Schema below. It is linked with User schema and I am using the Review schema with populate in my React page to get the User document data, i-e; fullName.
Is there a way i can get types around the User document when populated inside Review?
I've tried (review?.user as User)?.fullName) which I've attached as well.
import { Document, InferSchemaType, Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

export const ReviewSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    business: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business', required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 5 },
    comment: { type: String, required: false },
    images: { type: [String], required: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

export type Review = InferSchemaType<typeof ReviewSchema> & Document;

export const ReviewModel = models.Review || model('Review', ReviewSchema);


import { Document, InferSchemaType, Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, 'Email already exists!'],
    required: [true, 'Email is required!'],
  },
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Fullname is required!'],
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin', 'owner'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: { type: String },
  image: { type: String },
  businesses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business' }],
});

export type User = InferSchemaType<typeof UserSchema> & Document;
export const UserModel = models.User || model('User', UserSchema);





user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },

change this field -> userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }, and add new field user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed} and when you populate user for reviews, set {as: "user"} and then you can access user as entity.
it is not best solution for your case...

Yep. this might work similar to other workarounds but I'm looking for a generic solution.
